# "npx prisma generate" infinity loading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, prisma, typegraphql

Everything was working fine in my Windows machine, but in Ubuntu 20 when I run "npx prisma generate" or "npx prisma generate typegraphql" it never finishes.

The error:
[image]

The schema:
[image]

[EDIT] Now this error is being shown:
[image]

Comment: Versions:
dep
"@prisma/client": "3.6.0"
"type-graphql": "1.1.1"
dev dep
"typescript": "4.4.3"
"typegraphql-prisma": "0.18.2"

Comment: can you share your prisma schema please?

Comment: I added the image

Comment: I have generated it using prisma 3.6.0, @prisma/client 3.6.0 and typegraphql-prisma 0.18.2, and all works properly. I have only gotten an error which said that I should install prisma 3.6.0.

By the way, if you continue facing the problem, try to add the following configuration https://typegraphql.com/docs/installation.html